# Duplicate copy values from one columns value into another in python

Tags: python, duplicates, copy

I have data in one column with header as 'X'

I need the same data copied and created in another column as 'Y' in python jupyter. Any way i can do that.

Data:

```
X - 345,212,677
```

Required Output:

```
Y - 345,212,677
```

and on an incremental basis, if i add anything after 677, the same should be copied in column Y as well.

PS: Im a beginner for Python coding.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: yes pandas and numpy